# CSRF token error while using VirtualHost on apache

Tags: apache, http-headers, token, csrf, virtualhost

When I access through server IP, User sign in works perfect. But when I config virtual host for access by domain name, login form return:

> Failed to sign in! Please check your credentials and try again.

This is my config in Apache VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.top
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/prueba/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/prueba/
</VirtualHost>
```

I use basic jHipster login example, with Angular 1.x. The server is executed by war (java -jar file.war)

Thanks You!

Edited:

I find the problem. In login post request, CSRF tokens headers not founds. 
How I fix this?